# Свернуть асинхронный реквест и респонс через коллбек в один асинхронный метод

Tags: c#

Вопрос несколько творческий и скорее архитектурный.

Задача следующая, есть метод который принимает реквест и есть набор event(ов) через который отправляются ответы. К примеру:

```
interface IClient
{
    void GetSomethingRequest();
}

interface IObserver
{
    event Action SomethingRequestStatus;
    event Action<object> SomethingRequestResponse;
}
```

В примере есть сендер и обзервер. При вызове метода сендера, мы получаем один коллбек "SomethingRequestStatus" и n коллбеков "SomethingRequestResponse".

Вопрос такой, как правильнее свернуть всю эту конструкцию в один асинхронный метод наподобие слудующего:

```
interface IClient
{
    public Task<Tuple<bool, object>> GetSomething();
}
```

Думаю на счет мьютексов, но может есть более верное решение ?

Есть еще вариант с задержкой и проверкой заполнения ответов от коллбеков, однако задержки не подходят так как система должна работать быстро.

Иначе говоря вопрос в том как правильнее переписать старый вариант асинхронного процесса сделанный на основе коллбеков (используется взаимодействие с удаленным сервером через сокеты), на новый лад, где вызывая один метод можно дождаться ответа от системы.

Upd:

Основная проблема не в коллекционировании данных, а в задержки потока до момента прекращения прихода сообщений или же прихода события "SomethingRequestStatus" сигнализирующего о неудачном завершении запроса "client.GetSomethingRequest()".

Дело в том, что это межсервисное взаимодействие, но не по http, а через сокеты. Первый сервер отправляет запрос на второй. Второй сервер отвечает, а первый слушает ответ. т.е. метод client.GetSomethingRequest() - отправка запроса на второй сервер через сокет и все, этот метод не держит поток до завершения приема всех коллбеков.

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Comment: @aepot пока нет. Попробую Ваш метод несколько видоизменить. Однако основная проблема не в коллекционировании данных, а в задержки потока до момента прекращения прихода сообщений или же прихода события "SomethingRequestStatus" сигнализирующего о неудачном завершении запроса "client.GetSomethingRequest()".

Comment: @aepot Дело в том, что это межсервирное взаимодействие, но не по http, а через сокеты. Первый сервер отправляет запрос на второй. Второй сервер отвечает, а первый слушает ответ. 
т.е. метод client.GetSomethingRequest() - отправка запроса на второй сервер через сокет и все, этот метод не держит поток до завершения приема всех коллбеков.

Comment: _задержки потока до момента прекращения прихода сообщений_ - и как здесь понять, что настал конец прихода?

Comment: Это протокол какой? TCP или UDP? Почему именно сокеты используются? Что не позволило более высокоуровневое апи дотнета задействовать?

Comment: Вот примеров посмотреть про `TcpListener` https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A373567+TcpListener

Comment: @aepot Задача не в реализации работы с tcp протаколом. Я использую open source библиотеку которая под капотом использует сокеты. передача данных судя по информации что я нашел по библиотеке осуществляется по tcp. однако это уже отступления от вопроса. Смысл Вы поняли верно, взаимодействие идет по аналогии с чистой реализацией на tcp - один сервер отправил сообщение, другой получил, обработал и шлет ответы. Конечное количество ответов содержится в коллбек "SomethingRequestStatus". Основная задача - я не пойму как мне задерживать поток до момента прекращения получения ответов.

Comment: @aepot Как вариант рассматриваю объявление мьютекса и после приема последнего из сообщений освобождать мьютекс. Однако может быть есть более хорошее решение ?

Comment: _содержится в коллбек "SomethingRequestStatus"_ - у вас там ничего не может содержаться, там Action, нет аргументов. Обфускат логики сломал смысл кода в вопросе.

Comment: @aepot это был простой пример на интерфейсах даже. Написанных для Иллюстрации вопроса.

Comment: Ну вот на простой пример получился такой же простой код в ответе.

Comment: @aepot Не знаю конкретно область в которой Вы специализируетесь, так как с библиотека с которой я работаю в данный момент хоть и широко известна, однако она связана с узко направленной деятельностью и по этому что бы не ограничивать охват аудитории кто мог бы помочь в решении самой проблемы, я не стал ее указывать. 

Вот ссылка на нее:
https://github.com/connamara/quickfixn

Это библиотека для подключения к биржам по протаколу Fix. она асинхронна по своей сути, однако не поддерживает async await. и работает через сокеты. Мне эта асинхроность не всюду нужна и я ищу способы ее обойти.

Comment: Вы хотели получить async/await? Это не обход асинхроннлсти а преобразование одного асинхронного паттерна (EAP) в другой (TAP).

Comment: @aepot Именно это я и написал в вопросе но в самом конце :
"Иначе говоря вопрос в том как правильнее переписать старый вариант асинхронного процесса сделанный на основе коллбеков (используется взаимодействие с удаленным сервером через сокеты), на новый лад"

Однако как бы то ни было,  Ваш вариант тоже подходит с некоторыми доработками. Полностью готового ответа мне и не нужно.

Comment: Отлично, рад что смог помочь. На будущее: Необязательно показывать точный код в вопросе, но выбрасывая критичную логику и не объясняя её, получится либо недокод в ответе и стена комментов, либо вообще ничего не получится. Условия должны быть отражены достаточно конкретно, чтобы снизить вероятность получения неверного ответа к минимуму. Ваша задача простая, я промазал лишь потому, что было недостаточно исходной информации. Кстати, версию дотнета вы так и не указали, иногда это важно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как ответов много, без Producer/Consumer не обойтись. Будем считать, что `SomethingRequestStatus` это сигнал завершения приема данных. Тогда получится примерно такой метод.

```
public ChannelReader<object> GetSomething(IClient client, IObserver observer)
{
    Channel<object> channel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<object>();
    void dataHandler(object o) => channel.Writer.TryWrite(o);
    void statusHandler()
    {
        observer.SomethingRequestResponse -= dataHandler;
        observer.SomethingRequestStatus -= statusHandler;
        channel.Writer.Complete(); // закрывает канал
    }

    observer.SomethingRequestStatus += statusHandler;
    observer.SomethingRequestResponse += dataHandler;
    client.GetSomethingRequest();
    return channel.Reader;
}
```

А использовать его так

```
await foreach (object data in GetSomething().ReadAllAsync())
{
    UseData(data);
}
```

Comment: Благодарю за совет, однако у меня несколько сложнее задача. Ваше решение предполагает что метод client.GetSomethingRequest(); будет держать поток до завершения событий, а так же что SomethingRequestStatus - сигнал к завершению операции. У меня же все методы асинхронны. может сперва прийти событие SomethingRequestStatus где будет указан результат запроса client.GetSomethingRequest() (корректно или же нет. и так же там приходит количество вызовов второго события) события SomethingRequestStatus и SomethingRequestResponse  приходят в неустановленном заранее порядке.

Comment: @JamesBondCaesar никаких потоков это решение не держит. В каком месте вы это увидели вообще? Об остальных деталях я должен был сам догадаться? Перепишите вопрос так, чтобы не в угадайку играть и не тратить время на написание заведомо бесполезного кода, ок? GetSomethingRequest() синхронно вешает поток или что? Вы же сказали, что это асинхронное апи. Здесь ничего никого не держит.

Comment: В конце вопроса указано что это взаимодействие через сокеты и что это асинхронный процесс.

Comment: @JamesBondCaesar тогда где вы увидели что здесь что-то держит какой-то поток? Этот метод моментально выплюнет `ChannelReader` в вызывающий код.

Comment: @JamesBondCaesar из всего что вы рассказали я понял только то что надо как-то переписать метод `dataHandler` так, чтобы он вызывал `channel.Writer.Complete()` когда настал конец приема данных. Только и всего. И кстати, никто данные никуда не коллекционирует `UseData` это прием данных по мере их получения, практически сразу. `foreach` как раз задержит выполнения кода пока не будет вызван `Complete()`

Comment: Кажется понял идею. попробую покопать в этом направлении.